# What set do these parts come from?

Tags: piece-information, clone-brands

They are some of the most recognizable parts in a bag of a Lego set.[image]

Comment: Most of that doesn't look like LEGO. And don't shout.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! I've edited your post to use primarily lower case letters. All caps is generally frowned upon and can be considered rude.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, none of this is LEGO.

It's Kre-o and Megabloks (LEGO clone brands)

Some parts are from [Optimus Prime (30689)](http://kreo.wikia.com/wiki/Optimus_Prime_(30689))

The figures are probably Megabloks Halo